# single port ram with timming specifications

Tags: vhdl

```
generic(    -- read cycle
            constant taa : time := 120 ns;
                constant tacs: time := 120 ns;
                constant tclz: time := 10 ns;
                constant tchz :time := 10 ns;
                constant toh :time := 10 ns;
    -- write cycle begins           
                constant twc : time := 120 ns;
                constant taw:time := 105 ns;
                constant twp :time := 70 ns;
                constant twhz: time := 35 ns;
                constant tdw :time := 35 ns;
                constant tdh :time := 0 ns;
                constant tow :time := 10 ns);
type ramtype is array (0 downto 255) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ram: ramtype :=( others =>(others =>'0'));    

if(rising_edge(we) and cs'delayed = '0') or
            (falling_edge(cs) and we'delayed = '0') then 
                ram(conv_integer(address'delayed)) <= to_stdlogicvector(data'delayed); -- error here
                data <= transport data'delayed after tow;
            end if;
            if(falling_edge(we) and cs = '0') then 
                data <= transport "ZZZZZZZZ" after twhz;
            end if;

        if (cs'event ='1' and oe = '0') then  -- error here
                if cs = '1' then
                    data <= transport "ZZZZZZZZ" after tchz;
                elsif we = '1' then
                    data <= "XXXXXXXX" after tchz;
                    data <= transport to_stdlogicvector(ram(conv_integer(address))) after tacs; --error here
                end if;
            end if;

            if address'event and cs = '0' and oe = '0' and we = '1' then 
                    data <= "XXXXXXXX" after toh;
                    data <= transport to_stdlogicvector(ram(conv_integer(address))) after taa; -- error here
            end if;

        end process;
    end Behavioral;
```

getting errors in the following lines saying that 
Line 77: Expecting type natural for .
Line 77: Indexed name is not a std_logic_vector
Line 72: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "="
Line 83: Formal  has no actual or default value.
Line 83: Expecting type natural for .
ine 83: Indexed name is not a std_logic_vector

unable to figure out what might be the exact error

Comment: Line 65: Formal <b> has no actual or default value.
Line 65: Attribute delayed does not return type natural
Line 65: Indexed name is not a std_logic_vector
Formal <b> has no actual or default value.
ine 77: Expecting type natural for <ram>.
 Line 77: Indexed name is not a std_logic_vector 
Line 72: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "=" 
Line 83: Formal has no actual or default value. 
Line 83: Expecting type natural for . 
ine 83: Indexed name is not a std_logic_vector

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to directly comment in response to your own questions or answers - you can *edit* your question if you have more information to add.

Comment: "unable to figure out what might be the exact error" at line 77. As there are only 42 lines, neither are we. But it probably relates to some code you aren't showing us. Simplify to the SMALLEST COMPLETE source file that produces the error, and post THAT with the EXACT errors in an edit to the question. Also that code is quite poorly formatted so it's not very readable. Fix that too. In the process of doing the above you are likely to find the error yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  I filled in the blanks it got it to analyze:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity single_port_ram is
    generic (    
        -- read cycle
        constant taa:   time := 120 ns;
        constant tacs:  time := 120 ns;
        constant tclz:  time := 10 ns;
        constant tchz:  time := 10 ns;
        constant toh:   time := 10 ns;
        -- write cycle begins           
        constant twc:   time := 120 ns;
        constant taw:   time := 105 ns;
        constant twp:   time := 70 ns;
        constant twhz:  time := 35 ns;
        constant tdw:   time := 35 ns;
        constant tdh:   time := 0 ns;
        constant tow:   time := 10 ns
    );
    port (
        address:    in      std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        data:       inout   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        we:         in      std_logic;
        cs:         in      std_logic;
        oe:         in      std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of single_port_ram is

type ramtype is array (0 downto 255) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ram: ramtype :=( others =>(others =>'0')); 

begin


SINGLE_PROCESS:
    process(we, cs, address, data, oe)
    begin
        if ( rising_edge(we) and cs'delayed = '0') or
           (falling_edge(cs) and we'delayed = '0') then 
            ram(to_integer(unsigned (address'delayed))) <=  data'delayed;
            -- to_stdlogicvector(data'delayed); -- error here
            data <= transport data'delayed after tow;
        end if;

        if(falling_edge(we) and cs = '0') then 
            data <= transport "ZZZZZZZZ" after twhz;
        end if;

        if (cs'event  and oe = '0') then  -- error here -- cs'event = '1'
            if cs = '1' then
                data <= transport "ZZZZZZZZ" after tchz;
             elsif we = '1' then
                data <= "XXXXXXXX" after tchz;
                data <= transport std_logic_vector(ram(to_integer(unsigned(address)))) after tacs; --error here
            end if;
        end if;

         if address'event and cs = '0' and oe = '0' and we = '1' then 
                data <= "XXXXXXXX" after toh;
                data <= transport std_logic_vector(ram(to_integer(unsigned(address)))) after taa; -- error here
        end if;

    end process;
end behavioral;
```

I'm not vouching for it's functionality without a test bench.

From the unsigned type conversions you could gather this is done on a pre VHDL-2008 package numeric_std tool (ghdl).  In -2008 std_logic_vector and unsigned are both resolved subtypes of std_ulogic_vector.  The unsigned type conversion wouldn't be necessary.

You seem to have been using a Mentor Graphics version of the IEEE library, package std_logic_arith if I'm not mistaken.

Note that 'EVENT returns a boolean, and an equality test against '1' doesn't analyze.  You're error marker comments are still present.

Package numeric_std provides to_integer instead of conv_integer.

And the original looked better, albeit implemented in type BIT where possible.

(This was originally taken from Charles H. Roth, Jr.'s 1998 book Digital System Design Using VHDL, Chapter 9 .  I went looking when I noticed the language of your question avoided claiming authorship).

```
-- memory model with timing (OE_b=0) 
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library bitlib;
use bitlib.bit_pack.all;

entity static_RAM is
    generic (
        constant tAA:   time := 120 ns; -- 6116 static CMOS RAM 
        constant tACS:  time := 120 ns; 
        constant tCLZ:  time := 10 ns; 
        constant tCHZ:  time := 10 ns; 
        constant tOH:   time := 10 ns; 
        constant tWC:   time := 120 ns; 
        constant tAW:   time := 105 ns; 
        constant tWP:   time := 70 ns; 
        constant tWHZ:  time := 35 ns; 
        constant tDW:   time := 35 ns; 
        constant tDH:   time := 0 ns;
        constant tOW:   time := 10 ns
    );
    port (
        CS_b, WE_b, OE_b:   in      bit;
        Address:            in      bit_vector(7 downto 0);
        Data:               inout   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := 
                                        (others => 'Z')
    ); 
end Static_RAM;

architecture SRAM of Static_RAM is

    type RAMtype is array(0 to 255) of bit_vector(7 downto 0); 
    signal RAM1: RAMtype := (others => (others => '0')); 
begin

RAM: 
    process 
    begin
        if (rising_edge(WE_b) and CS_b'delayed = '0') or 
           (rising_edge(CS_b) and WE_b'delayed = '0') then
            RAM1(vec2int(Address'delayed)) <= to_bitvector(Data'delayed);           --write 
            if CS_b = '0' then
                Data <= transport Data'delayed after tOW; 
            end if;
        end if;
        if falling_edge(WE_b) and CS_b = '0' then
            Data <= transport "ZZZZZZZZ" after tWHZ; 
        end if;
    --read back after write
        if CS_b'event and OE_b = '0' then
            if CS_b = '1' then 
                Data <= transport "ZZZZZZZZ" after tCHZ; 
            elsif WE_b = '1' then --read
                Data <= "XXXXXXXX" after tCLZ;
    -- RAM is deselected
                Data <= transport to_stdlogicvector(RAM1(vec2int(Address))) after tACS; 
            end if;
        end if;
        wait on CS_b, WE_b, Address;
    end process RAM;
check: 
    process 
    begin
    if CS_b'delayed = '0' and NOW /= 0 ns then 
        if address'event then
            assert (address'delayed'stable(tWC)) 
            -- tRC = tWC assumed report "Address cycle time too short"
            severity WARNING;
        end if;
        if rising_edge(WE_b) then
            assert (address'delayed'stable(tAW))
            report "Address not valid long enough to end of write"
            severity WARNING;
            assert (WE_b'delayed'stable(tWP))
            report "Write pulse too short"
            severity WARNING;
            assert (Data'delayed'stable(tDW))
            report "Data setup time too short"
            severity WARNING;
            wait for tDH;
            assert (Data'last_event >= tDH)
            report "Data hold time too short" 
            severity WARNING;
        end if;
    end if;
        wait on WE_b, address, CS_b;
    end process check;
end SRAM;
```

And the original converted cleanly:

```
-- memory model with timing (OE_b=0) 
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- library bitlib;
-- use bitlib.bit_pack.all;

entity static_RAM is
    generic (
        constant tAA:   time := 120 ns; -- 6116 static CMOS RAM 
        constant tACS:  time := 120 ns; 
        constant tCLZ:  time := 10 ns; 
        constant tCHZ:  time := 10 ns; 
        constant tOH:   time := 10 ns; 
        constant tWC:   time := 120 ns; 
        constant tAW:   time := 105 ns; 
        constant tWP:   time := 70 ns; 
        constant tWHZ:  time := 35 ns; 
        constant tDW:   time := 35 ns; 
        constant tDH:   time := 0 ns;
        constant tOW:   time := 10 ns
    );
    port (
        CS_b, WE_b, OE_b:   in      std_logic;
        Address:            in      std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Data:               inout   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := 
                                        (others => 'Z')
    ); 
end Static_RAM;

architecture SRAM of Static_RAM is

    type RAMtype is array(0 to 255) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
    signal RAM1: RAMtype := (others => (others => '0')); 
begin

RAM: 
    process 
    begin
        if (rising_edge(WE_b) and CS_b'delayed = '0') or 
           (rising_edge(CS_b) and WE_b'delayed = '0') then
            RAM1(to_integer(unsigned(Address'delayed))) 
                <= Data'delayed;           --write 
            if CS_b = '0' then
                Data <= transport Data'delayed after tOW; 
            end if;
        end if;
        if falling_edge(WE_b) and CS_b = '0' then
            Data <= transport "ZZZZZZZZ" after tWHZ; 
        end if;
    --read back after write
        if CS_b'event and OE_b = '0' then
            if CS_b = '1' then 
                Data <= transport "ZZZZZZZZ" after tCHZ; 
            elsif WE_b = '1' then --read
                Data <= "XXXXXXXX" after tCLZ;
    -- RAM is deselected
                Data <= transport RAM1(to_integer(unsigned(Address))) after tACS; 
            end if;
        end if;
        wait on CS_b, WE_b, Address;
    end process RAM;
check: 
    process 
    begin
    if CS_b'delayed = '0' and NOW /= 0 ns then 
        if address'event then
            assert (address'delayed'stable(tWC)) 
            -- tRC = tWC assumed report "Address cycle time too short"
            severity WARNING;
        end if;
        if rising_edge(WE_b) then
            assert (address'delayed'stable(tAW))
            report "Address not valid long enough to end of write"
            severity WARNING;
            assert (WE_b'delayed'stable(tWP))
            report "Write pulse too short"
            severity WARNING;
            assert (Data'delayed'stable(tDW))
            report "Data setup time too short"
            severity WARNING;
            wait for tDH;
            assert (Data'last_event >= tDH)
            report "Data hold time too short" 
            severity WARNING;
        end if;
    end if;
        wait on WE_b, address, CS_b;
    end process check;
end SRAM;
```

And analyzes.

**addendum**

The questioner commented on the use of BITLIB, so I went looking.

The book author has a resource page ([Digital Systems Design Using VHDL](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~roth/VHDL_book/book.htm)) and the VHDL source code found in the be found [here](http://www.ece.uah.edu/~gaede/cpe422/book_vhdl/) indexed by chapter and figure numbers from the book. The BITLIB library VHDL code is found in Bit_pack.vhd,

A little looking around last night also reveals there's a second edition of the book published in 2008.

Comment: Thank u sir that was very helpfull and by the way, when i'm using the bitlib library it get an error that bit is not found in the <bit_pack>